# in django change data at template via jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

```
def post_list(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=1)
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=3)
    post_list = posts[:20]
    return render(request, '...html', {'post_list': post_list})
```

here is script; script's alert works but post_list doesn't change

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#some').change(function () {
    var some= $('#some').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'user_id': some,
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('work');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("don't work");
        }
    });
});


url(r'^$', post_list, name='post_list'),
```

Comment: You have to insert the data from the callback into your html template. Also your type ist GET and not POST...

Answer (score 0):

You need some jQuery code to add the items returned to your HTML.  Something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
        alert('work');
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              $("#some_unordered_list").append('<li>'+val+'</li>');
        });
```